# get array with in JSON array in web method? How to?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, json

i have a working ajax function with web method without getting string[] address or any other array string [] abc , in parameter , My arrays within array is

```
  MDate: "04-08-2015"
  MPurpose: 1
  MTime: "1010"
  RowNumber: 2
  address: Array[1]
  cell: Array[1]
  company: Array[1]
  designation: Array[1]
  id: "0"
  masterID: 0
  name: Array[1]
  nic: Array[1]
```

after JSON.STRINGIFY it becomes

```
  "{"name":["nouman","nouman"],"nic":["9089898","9089898"],"designation":  ["jkkhjk","jkkhjk"],"company":["uk","uk"],"cell":["+923012324265","+923012324265"],"address":["hkjhjk","hkjhjk"],"id":"0","MDate":"04-08-2015","MTime":"1010","MPurpose":1,"masterID":0,"RowNumber":3}"
```

their are 2 adresses , cell etc as array[]

my ajax method correct

```
  $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "AddNewMeeting.aspx/SetFileName",
             contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
             data: JSON.stringify(Meeting),

             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {

                 alert(data);

             },
             error: function (result) {
                 //alert("Error login");

             }
         });
     }
```

my web method works only when i use parameters other then arrays like adress , cell etc

```
     [WebMethod]
    public static string SetFileName(string MDate, int MPurpose, string MTime, int RowNumber)
    {
        string c = "d";
        return c;
    }
```

i want to recieve

```
   //string[] address, string[] cell, string[] company, string[] designation, int id, int masterID, string[] name, string[] nic)
```

also in parameter but how it would not work

Comment: then directly pass accordingly a data.address, data.cell,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send arrays as parameter like this

> companyArray = ['Value1', 'Value2'] 
>   result = { MDate: "04-08-2015", companies: companyArray  }
>   return JSON.stringify(result)

Where web service will be

> public string webService(string MDate, string[] companies)

It works for me

Comment: In your case result object will be Meeting. to send as data in ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `traditional` property to your AJAX request, set it to `true` and remove the `JSON.stringify`:

```
var meetingData = {
    MDate: "04-08-2015",
    MPurpose: 1,
    MTime: "1010",
    RowNumber: 2,
    address: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
    cell: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
    company: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
    designation: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
    id: "0",
    masterID: 0,
    name: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
    nic: [ 'string1', 'string2' ],
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddNewMeeting.aspx/SetFileName",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: meetingData,
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error login");
    }
});
```